# execute functions after a dynamically created div's content(like images) is loaded, using jQuery

Tags: jquery, delegates, load

i want to execute some functions only after a dynamically created DIV's content (which will includes text and images) is loaded completely. Here the dynamically created DIV is "#element"+data.

The below is not working.

```
$("#section"+currSect).delegate( "#element"+data, "load", function()
{ remvPanel(); showFormBox(); }
);
```

This also not working.

```
 $("#element"+data).load(function() {remvPanel(); showFormBox();});
```

Please Help! :(

Comment: Why delegate to just one element?

Comment: Yeah but you can dynamically add an event handler to the element when you create it. I'm not sure but I wonder if the event handler created this way would be removed if you deleted the element it's working for.

Comment: I did: attach the event handler to the element when you create it. How is it created? Via jquery, or loaded HTML?

Comment: via jquery using createElement.

Comment: Did you try adding the `.load` event handler after you add the element to the DOM?

Answer (score 0):

Will this do it?

[jQuery .load()](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/)

This method is a shortcut for .bind('load', handler).

The load event is sent to an element when it and all sub-elements have been completely loaded. This event can be sent to any element associated with a URL: images, scripts, frames, iframes, and the window object.

For example, consider a page with a simple image:

```
<img src="book.png" alt="Book" id="book" />
```

The event handler can be bound to the image:

```
$('#book').load(function() {
  // Handler for .load() called.
});
```

A working example:

```
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $div = $("#main");

            // get loaded alert
            $img = $("<img src='https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png' />");

            // no loaded alert
            // $img = $("<img src='not a valid image' />");

            $img.load(function () {
                alert("loaded");
            });

            $div.append($img);
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="main">
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I added a complete example. Specifically, what is not working?

Comment: Maybe provider a more complete code sample. I can't help you beyond this with what you have provided.