# How soon can I retrieve a DOM element's size?

Tags: jquery

I'm using the `window.load` event to make an ajax call to retrieve some html, which I then use in populating the .html attribute of an `<li>` element.  This works, though the performance could be better since everything has to be loaded before my call begins.

As part of this ajax call one of the parameters is the `<li>`'s `outerWidth` value.  However, when I try making the ajax call in, say, the `document.ready` handler the `outerWidth` is not properly set.  I assume that's because the DOM elements haven't had a chance to know their final sizes at that point.  However, is there an event I can handle before `document.ready` fires in which I would know the element's size?  Something between `window.load` and `document.ready`?

I've also used jQuery mobile's pageinit event in lieu of `document.ready` but there was no difference in this case, which is understandable.  I'll be using pageinit going forward fwiw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `load()` on a specific DOM element instead of on `window`.

[jQuery .load()](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/)

This method is a shortcut for `.bind('load', handler)`.

The load event is sent to an element when it and all sub-elements have been completely loaded. This event can be sent to any element associated with a URL: images, scripts, frames, iframes, and the window object.

By binding to the load event on your specific DOM element, you won't have to wait for other (non-sub) items to render and should have better performance. `window.load()`, as you have discovered, will wait for all sub-elements to load.

For example, consider a page with a simple image:

```
<img src="book.png" alt="Book" id="book" />
```

The event handler can be bound to the image:

```
$('#book').load(function() {
  // Handler for .load() called.
});
```

Comment: After a bit more testing and reading, you are correct. But now I am a bit confused: are you reading this value and sending it back to the server? If you just want to set it based on a value on your server, then just set it. No need to wait for the item to be fully rendered.

Comment: Be careful when posting copy and paste boilerplate/verbatim answers to multiple questions, these tend to be flagged as "spammy" by the community. If you're doing this then it usually means the questions are duplicates so flag them as such instead: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13031064

Comment: @andleer-- the <li> tag is being used as a parent to hold an href and img tag (<li><a href=..><img></img></a></li>), which are generated via an ajax call to google maps.  I can't set its value on the server because the image size will depend on the size of the device's screen.

Comment: @Kev, understand and good point. It wasn't my intention but yes, pretty much the same question / answer.